# Website using Phonenumber, frequently getting phone calls from strangers

Tags: internet, privacy, germany, phonecall

A website is using the mobile/cellphone number of a relative in their contacts. He's getting phone calls from strangers multiple times a week, sometimes even multiple times a day. He's not to familiar with the internet and asked me about what to do. I don't know whether the entire website is a scam. So contacting them might not work.

Considering the frequency of the calls and how often they call even after declining the call it might be that their website is no scam. But this going on for months and at some point you have to notice that you have the wrong number in the contact.

So what can one do about this misuse of a phone number? Are there any laws I can mention when trying to contact them? Are there any other options besides contacting them by myself or hiring a lawyer?

Changing the phonenumber is not an option.

EDIT: He already contacted them and they didn't reply.

Comment: This sounds more like a mistake than something nefarious. Does the website have any other contact form (e-mail, phisical address, a form) to notify them? Another alternative is an internet service called "whois" that gives you the name of whoever registered the domain.

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks! I think he already tried to contact them. We just talked about it yesterday and he also thought about contacting a laywer. I will visit him today and add all the (non-personal) information to the question.

Comment: One option is to say every time "No, I don't offer that service, the website's lying. Why don't you write in and complain?"